# "jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: certificate exception" while trying to manually sign an APK

Tags: android, android-studio, jarsigner

Im suddenly unable to manually sign my application.

It used to work until now.

The only thing I remember changing is android studio to version 2.3.2

I'm getting this error:

> jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: certificate exception:
>   Unable to initialize, java.io.IOException: DerInputStream.getLength():
>   Redundant length bytes found

This is the command that I run:

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my_keystore.keystore some-unsigned.apk alias
```

I tried to refer this post:
[PKCS#12 : DerInputStream.getLength() exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399154/pkcs12-derinputstream-getlength-exception)

but unfortunately I'm getting a different exception

No idea what to do

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PKCS#12 : DerInputStream.getLength() exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399154/pkcs12-derinputstream-getlength-exception)

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399154/pkcs12-derinputstream-getlength-exception

Comment: @LunarWatcher I don't see how it related to my problem as I'm getting a different exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found the solution

The problem is the version of java that installed.

It seems like that there is a problem (at least for me...) with the newest version of java (at that moment of writing: 8u131)

I tried that on another mac which has 8u101 version and it worked, so I downgraded it on my mac and it worked either.

In case it helps anyone...