# "Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'." for brand new expo bare workflow app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I run

```
expo init
```

and choose

```
minimal               bare and minimal, just the essentials to get you started
```

for the bare workflow. I then change to my apps directory and run

```
yarn android
```

with my htc android phone plugged in and this is the output

```
yarn android
yarn run v1.15.2
$ react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1161 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

> Configure project :app

Installing unimodules:
 unimodules-core@5.1.0 from /Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/node_modules/@unimodules/core
 unimodules-react-native-adapter@5.2.0 from /Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/node_modules/@unimodules/react-native-adapter
 expo-constants@9.0.0 from /Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/node_modules/expo-constants
 expo-error-recovery@1.1.0 from /Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/node_modules/expo-error-recovery
 expo-file-system@8.1.0 from /Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/node_modules/expo-file-system
 expo-font@8.1.0 from /Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/node_modules/expo-font
 expo-image-loader@1.0.1 from /Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/node_modules/expo-image-loader
 expo-keep-awake@8.1.0 from /Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/node_modules/expo-keep-awake
 expo-linear-gradient@8.1.0 from /Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/node_modules/expo-linear-gradient
 expo-location@8.1.0 from /Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/node_modules/expo-location
 expo-permissions@8.1.0 from /Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/node_modules/expo-permissions
 expo-sqlite@8.1.0 from /Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/node_modules/expo-sqlite
 expo-updates@0.1.2 from /Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/node_modules/expo-updates
 expo-web-browser@8.1.0 from /Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/node_modules/expo-web-browser
 unimodules-app-loader@1.0.1 from /Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/node_modules/unimodules-app-loader
 unimodules-barcode-scanner-interface@5.1.0 from /Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/node_modules/unimodules-barcode-
scanner-interface
 unimodules-camera-interface@5.1.0 from /Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/node_modules/unimodules-camera-interface
 unimodules-constants-interface@5.1.0 from /Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/node_modules/unimodules-constants-interface
 unimodules-face-detector-interface@5.1.0 from /Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/node_modules/unimodules-face-detector-interface
 unimodules-file-system-interface@5.1.0 from /Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/node_modules/unimodules-file-system-interface
 unimodules-font-interface@5.1.0 from /Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/node_modules/unimodules-font-interface
 unimodules-image-loader-interface@5.1.0 from /Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/node_modules/unimodules-image-loader-interface
 unimodules-permissions-interface@5.1.0 from /Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/node_modules/unimodules-permissions-interface
 unimodules-sensors-interface@5.1.0 from /Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/node_modules/unimodules-sensors-interface
 unimodules-task-manager-interface@5.1.0 from /Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/node_modules/unimodules-task-manager-interface

> Task :unimodules-core:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :expo-constants:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :expo-file-system:processDebugManifest
/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/node_modules/expo-file-system/android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:10:9-21:20 War
ning:
        provider#expo.modules.filesystem.FileSystemFileProvider@android:authorities was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:10 to replac
e other declarations but no other declaration present

> Task :expo-file-system:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :expo-image-loader:compileDebugKotlin
w: /Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/node_modules/expo-image-loader/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/imageloader/
ImageLoaderModule.kt: (11, 42): 'SimpleTarget<Z : Any!>' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: /Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/node_modules/expo-image-loader/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/imageloader/
ImageLoaderModule.kt: (83, 22): 'SimpleTarget<Z : Any!>' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

> Task :expo-location:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :expo-sqlite:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :expo-updates:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Gradle may disable incremental compilation as the following annotation processors are not incremental: room-compiler-2.1.0.jar (an
droidx.room:room-compiler:2.1.0).
Consider setting the experimental feature flag android.enableSeparateAnnotationProcessing=true in the gradle.properties file to ru
n annotation processing in a separate task and make compilation incremental.

> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :react-native-reanimated:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :unimodules-app-loader:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :react-native-screens:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :app:processDebugManifest
/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:18:9-27:20 Warning:
        provider#expo.modules.filesystem.FileSystemFileProvider@android:authorities was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:18 to replac
e other declarations but no other declaration present
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug
/out/lib/armeabi-v7a/libhermes-inspector.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARMEABI_V7A'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug
/out/lib/armeabi-v7a/libnative-filters.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARMEABI_V7A'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug
/out/lib/armeabi-v7a/libreactnativeblob.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARMEABI_V7A'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/armeabi-v7a/libnative-imagetranscoder.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARMEABI_V7A'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/armeabi-v7a/libjsc.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARMEABI_V7A'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug
/out/lib/x86/libfb.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'X86'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug
/out/lib/x86/libreactnativejni.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'X86'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug
/out/lib/x86/libyoga.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'X86'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/arm64-v8a/libjsc.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARM64_V8A'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug
/out/lib/arm64-v8a/libreactnativejni.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARM64_V8A'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug
/out/lib/x86_64/libjsijniprofiler.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'X86_64'. Packaging it as is.

> Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols
Compatible side by side NDK version was not found.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug
/out/lib/armeabi-v7a/libjsijniprofiler.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARMEABI_V7A'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/armeabi-v7a/libjsinspector.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARMEABI_V7A'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/armeabi-v7a/libfolly_json.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARMEABI_V7A'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/armeabi-v7a/libglog.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARMEABI_V7A'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/armeabi-v7a/libimagepipeline.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARMEABI_V7A'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/armeabi-v7a/libglog_init.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARMEABI_V7A'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/armeabi-v7a/libfolly_futures.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARMEABI_V7A'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/armeabi-v7a/libhermes-executor-debug.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARMEABI_V7A'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARMEABI_V7A'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/armeabi-v7a/libhermes-executor-release.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARMEABI_V7A'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/armeabi-v7a/libfb.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARMEABI_V7A'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/armeabi-v7a/libjscexecutor.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARMEABI_V7A'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/armeabi-v7a/libreactnativejni.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARMEABI_V7A'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/armeabi-v7a/libyoga.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARMEABI_V7A'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/x86/libhermes-inspector.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'X86'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/x86/libjsc.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'X86'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/x86/libjsijniprofiler.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'X86'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/x86/libglog_init.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'X86'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/x86/libfolly_futures.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'X86'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/x86/libhermes-executor-debug.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'X86'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/x86/libc++_shared.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'X86'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/x86/libhermes-executor-release.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'X86'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/x86/libjscexecutor.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'X86'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/arm64-v8a/libhermes-inspector.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARM64_V8A'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/arm64-v8a/libnative-filters.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARM64_V8A'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/arm64-v8a/libreactnativeblob.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARM64_V8A'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/arm64-v8a/libnative-imagetranscoder.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARM64_V8A'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/arm64-v8a/libjsijniprofiler.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARM64_V8A'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/arm64-v8a/libjsinspector.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARM64_V8A'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/arm64-v8a/libfb.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARM64_V8A'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/arm64-v8a/libyoga.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARM64_V8A'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/x86_64/libhermes-inspector.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'X86_64'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/x86_64/libnative-filters.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'X86_64'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/x86_64/libreactnativeblob.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'X86_64'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/x86_64/libjsc.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'X86_64'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/x86_64/libjsinspector.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'X86_64'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/x86_64/libfolly_json.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'X86_64'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/x86_64/libglog.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'X86_64'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/x86_64/libimagepipeline.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'X86_64'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/x86_64/libglog_init.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'X86_64'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/x86_64/libfolly_futures.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'X86_64'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/x86_64/libhermes-executor-debug.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'X86_64'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'X86_64'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/x86_64/libhermes-executor-release.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'X86_64'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/x86_64/libfb.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'X86_64'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/x86_64/libjscexecutor.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'X86_64'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/x86_64/libreactnativejni.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'X86_64'. Packaging it as is.
Unable to strip library '/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_native_libs/debug/out/lib/x86_64/libyoga.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'X86_64'. Packaging it as is.

> Task :app:packageDebug FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.6.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
564 actionable tasks: 564 executed
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: /Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/node_modules/expo-constants/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/constants/Co
nstantsService.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/node_modules/expo-file-system/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/filesystem/FileSystemModule.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: /Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/node_modules/expo-location/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/location/taskConsumers/GeofencingTaskConsumer.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: /Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/node_modules/expo-sqlite/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/sqlite/SQLiteModule.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: /Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/gesturehandler/react/RNGestureHandlerButtonViewManager.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: /Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/reanimated/NodesManager.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/reanimated/NodesManager.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: /Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/node_modules/unimodules-app-loader/android/src/org/unimodules/apploader/AppLoaderProvider.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key androiddebugkey from store "/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/debug.keystore": DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=63, too big.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 23s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: /Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/node_modules/expo-constants/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/constants/ConstantsService.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/node_modules/expo-file-system/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/filesystem/FileSystemModule.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: /Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/node_modules/expo-location/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/location/taskConsumers/GeofencingTaskConsumer.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: /Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/node_modules/expo-sqlite/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/sqlite/SQLiteModule.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: /Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/gesturehandler/react/RNGestureHandlerButtonViewManager.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: /Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/reanimated/NodesManager.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/reanimated/NodesManager.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: /Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/node_modules/unimodules-app-loader/android/src/org/unimodules/apploader/AppLoaderProvider.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key androiddebugkey from store "/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/android/app/debug.keystore": DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=63, too big.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 23s

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:610:11)
    at execFileSync (child_process.js:628:15)
    at runOnAllDevices (/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:94:39)
    at buildAndRun (/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js:179:41)
    at /Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js:133:12
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (/Users/Sam/Documents/firebase_dummy_app/chatroom/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:182:9)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

---

I get the same output if I build in the managed workflow and then run `expo eject`

Comment: This answer solved it https://stackoverflow.com/a/56951897/6331353

Comment: Could you tell me about your solution more detail? I met the same problem with you.